# Why do people support/oppose the death penalty (with article), but oppose/support abortion (no article)

Tags: articles

Why is the article **the** used when talking about the death penalty, but isn't used when discussing abortion?

Comment: Because there are several penalties, of which the death penalty is one, whereas there is only one kind of abortion.

Comment: That's not necessarily true; if that were entirely true, then it seems that someone could oppose "_the_ late-term abortion".

Comment: "Abortion of late term" doesn't work, where as "penalty of death" does.  Ours is a strange language.

Comment: This is because the type of penalty is (half-)particular thanks to "death", while abortion is used as a general noun.

Comment: @DougM "penalty of death" doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps mine is an unusually strange language :-)

Comment: "In Robin Hood's day, English citizens were forbidden to kill the king's deer, under penalty of death."

Comment: You could say "I support penalty" or "I don't support penalty" referring to punishing anyone for anything in general.

Comment: It would have been better to contrast *"the death penalty"* with *"execution"*.

Comment: This feels like a problem purely stemming from speaking native Russians. The usage of articles seems to go a little haywire sometimes when they aren't used in ones native language. I don't think the question is a great fit for this site.

Comment: @SvenYargs *Sub poena mortis*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*The death penalty* is referred to with an article because it is a specific thing—a *penalty*.  It refers to something written in law, rather than all instances of it.  There are multiple instances of the death penalty, referred to as *[death sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment)*.

In the linked article, another term for *the death penalty* is *capital punishment*.  This does not use the definite article because *punishment* is a general idea—a term for the imposition of a *penalty*.  We could, of course, say *the punishment* but that would refer to a specific instance of it.

Similarly, when talking about *abortion*, it is the general idea we are talking about—not something written somewhere in law books.  There is no specific abortion we are talking about, no specific thing we can refer to as *the* abortion, unless we talk about an instance of it.

[Here](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-not-to-use-the-definite-article/)'s a web page about when to not use *the* in English.  Similar *general* things that do not need articles include

> I like listening to *music*.
>
> I watch *sports*.

Whereas, when we refer to a particular instance of these things:

> I like listening to *the music you sent me*.
>
> I watched *the Bears game*.

Comment: Are there other types of penalties to which we refer using _the_? I can't think of any.

Comment: That's because most other penalties aren't referred to using *penalty* at all—like *jail time* or *community service*.  But in general, I'd refer to a particular penalty (something defined as a penalty by law) as *the penalty* or *a penalty*.  For example, there's *a penalty* for selling drugs which is generally jail time.

Comment: Sure, there's *the **maximum** penalty*, *the **minimum** penalty*, *the **standard** penalty*, *the **first** penalty*, and any number of jurisdiction-specific named penalties analogous to the death penalty; for example, in ice hockey, there's *the **match** penalty*.

Comment: There's actually an interesting division here: some penalties are named for the crime, e.g. *the **late** penalty* (which is the penalty for the crime of being **late**), vs penalties named for the consequences (the penalties themselves), such as *the **death** penalty* (you pay for the crime with your life) or *the **tax** penalty* (you pay for the crime with increased taxes). Most "named" penalties name the crime; only a few, usually most severe (and therefore "most unique") name the consequences.

Comment: +1 I think it's worth mentioning that one would refer to the *law* relating to abortion as (eg in the UK) "The Abortion Act", and it's *that* that is analogous to "The Death Penalty". These things take "the" because they are specific things. "Abortion" isn't, in the same way that "Capital Punishment" isn't.

Comment: @MattGutting the penalty of a downvote

Comment: Rupe: but lawyers and academics discuss *abortion law* as a field, just as they discuss *tax law*. *The Abortion Act* is one specific instance of abortion law.

Comment: @TimLymington Just as *The Death Penalty* is one specific instance of a punishment for committing crime, whereas *punishment* would be the field in terms of law.

Comment: @TimLymington Right, and that provides a good example of what the "the" does. "Abortion Law" is a general term as you say, but "the Abortion Law" would be referring to a specific law (whether that means a specific Act or "the law as it is at a specific time").

Answer (score -4):

Emphasis and politics. By using the the term "the" in front of a word in a title, it's emphasis that term and also narrows it down to a single topic.

Example:

1. A Death Penalty
2. The Death Penalty

As a reader, which one do you think has the more meaning and impact? I could talk about 'a' death penalty, but when the word 'the' is mentioned in front of a penalty, it becomes a single entity.

Imagine the difference between The Death Penalty and Abortion.

1. The Death Penalty
2. The Abortion

When using the term "the" in front of abortion, it's meaning changes. It has more emphasis and is no longer consider a loose terminology! Both the death penalty and abortion involve deaths, but one type of death is considered "more important" than another death. That's the political half and the reason why "the" is used for the death penalty compared to abortion.

The older practices were "sacrifices" in which youth and newborns were killed in order to appease a God in a ritual. Today's unborn youth (Generation Z) are killed by their parents (Generation X) through abortion by help of medical science. When there were wars, parents were concern of the life of their children, but since there has not been another world war, this care has been replaced with politics which extends past from the Baby Boomber (BB) generation.

It's quiet strange how the human eyes and ears are trained to react to certain words in the English language. There is a reason for it. :)

Comment: This is nonsense.